# How do I keep an svn:external up to date using git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, dvcs

Treating my repository as a SVN repo, I get:

```
svn co http://myrepo/foo/trunk foo
...
foo/
  bar/
  baz/ -> http://myrepo/baz/trunk
```

Treating it as a Git repo, I get:

```
git svn clone http://myrepo/foo --trunk=trunk --branches=branches --tags=tags
...
foo/
  bar/
```

I can clone baz to my local machine elsewhere and add a symlink, but that's just a hack.  Is there a way to have `git svn rebase` automatically pull in those changes when it updates everything else, just like `svn up` does?

Comment: I know I've read somewhere about how to set this up with git submodules, but I can't find the link.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was just to symlink to other `git-svn` clones on my local box.  This worked pretty well: it allows me to commit changes back, and it allows me to make local changes on project A just to get them into project B.

Answer (score 26):

The best means of integrating svn externals with git-svn that I've seen is this [script](http://github.com/andrep/git-svn-clone-externals/tree/master), which clones your externals into a .git_externals/ directory and creates the symlinks and exclude files you need. I find this a simple and direct solution. YMMV.

Here is an [older overview](http://panthersoftware.com/articles/view/3/svn-s-svn-externals-to-git-s-submodule-for-rails-plugins) of other options for dealing with svn externals with git-svn. To me they look a little over-complicated and liable to break under subsequent Git use.

Comment: This seems not to work for me (here the externals are relative links to the same repository).

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote a short script which checkouts all `svn:externals` of the current `HEAD` to the root directory and excludes them from the git repository.

Place it to `.git/hooks/post-checkout` and it will keep those external checkouts up to date whenever the working tree changes, for example due to `git svn rebase` or `git-checkout`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

revision=$(git svn info | sed -n 's/^Revision: \([1-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/p')
git svn -r${revision} propget svn:externals | head -n-1 | {
    while read checkout_args
    do
        checkout_dirname=$(echo ${checkout_args} | cut -d' ' -f3)
        svn checkout ${checkout_args}
        if [ -z $(grep ${checkout_dirname} .git/info/exclude) ]
        then
            echo ${checkout_dirname} >> .git/info/exclude
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: +1 for something that almost works on windows git.  I had to tweak it a little bit, but it's the best solution on here for windows.

Comment: @pms1969: Source for the tweaked version?

Answer (score 4):

I also made a script (both Perl and Ruby variants available) that does this for me, it's at http://github.com/liyanage/git-tools/.

- Recursively checks out all svn:externals
- Can be run repeatedly in case the clone of a large repository aborts halfway through. Happened to me a lot. It picks up where it left off.
- Adds all svn:externals entries it finds and processes to .git/info/exclude
- Adds all svn:ignore entries it encounters to .git/info/exclude
- Can be run regularly after the first run to do the svn:rebase in all cloned sub-sandboxes, discover new externals and new svn:ignores

Update: I am no longer maintaining this script. Its functionality for recursively cloning and updating an SVN repository, as well as other git-related features, is available in this newer project that I am actively maintaining: http://liyanage.github.com/git-tools/

Comment: I'd like to learn what didn't work for you so I can improve the script. Can you contact me?

Comment: There's a lot of forks. Does anyone know which one of them works on windows with msysgit? The linked version just hangs.

Comment: Couldn't make it work either. The documentation seems out of sync. `gh clone-externals` is not recognized as a valid subcommand.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520782/158074) suggestion and tried using [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/index.html) for dealing with `svn:externals`.

SmartGit is by far the best GUI client I've ever seen for Git. Regarding `svn:externals`, it not only correctly fetches them, but also presents the option of doing a "fast snapshot" (read-only, HEAD-only clone) of external repositories.

Unfortunately it is not free for commercial use (and I found the license price a little bit too high - yes I'm a cheapskate). It may be used for free for non-commercial purposes though.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write a "simple" perl script to handle all this stuff for me. I've put it recently to github, try it out, maybe it would help: http://github.com/sushdm/git_svn_externals/.

It essentially does git-svn clone for all externals found, and it looks for them recursively, clones, symlinks them in proper places and excludes all .git_externals dirs and symlinks so that you can still use 'git svn dcommit'.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

try this python script https://bitbucket.org/nytmyn/gitsvnext/overview

to checkout svn externals run following in your git repository

```
python /../gitsvnext/run update
```

run this to know what to put to .git/info/exclude

```
python /../gitsvnext/run list
```

Comment: Which folder would you run this against? If my main svn repository is /path/to/repo and the externals are defined inside /path/to/repo/myexternals/folder/ then should I run the script inside /path/to/repo or myexternals/folder?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done.

First I created an empty SVN repo (for the same root as the git):

```
svn checkout --depth empty http://path/to/repo .
```

This created empty svn repo in the git root. The point is that is contains the SVN externals properties.

Next I simply check only the externals (I placed in PATH cygwin tools):

```
svn propget svn:externals | sed -e 's/ / .\//' | sed -e 's/\'//g' | xargs -L1 svn co
```