# A true, robust, git svn externals solution?

Tags: git, git-svn, svn-externals

When you check out a git repository that contains svn externals, it will simply ignore them. What people have done is create many scripts, many of them mentioned in this question [How do I keep an svn:external up to date using git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350651/how-do-i-keep-an-svnexternal-up-to-date-using-git-svn). The problem is that while numerous scripts are floating on the internet, I have yet to find one that was actually robust. By robust, I mean specifically:

1. It can handle svn externals pegged to a particular revision
2. It can handle svn externals that point to a file instead of a directory

Because these are 2 issues with my repository that seem to bring most scripts down. I have no interest in using smartgit.

Is there such a script? Does anyone have a script that is "almost there" that could be adapted to these 2 things rather quickly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git & svn externals - a final solution yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689090/git-svn-externals-a-final-solution-yet)

Comment: Maybe switching to _subgit_ is a better course for you?

Comment: subgit does not support yet svn externals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no perfect solution that just works. You can refer to:

[How do I keep an svn:external up to date using git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350651/how-do-i-keep-an-svnexternal-up-to-date-using-git-svn)

[git & svn externals - a final solution yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689090/git-svn-externals-a-final-solution-yet)