# git svn - clone repo with all externals

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn-externals

I want to use git to clone a svn repository, but unfortunately, where `svn checkout` gets the repo with all externals, `git svn clone` only gets the repository without externals. How can I get the externals from the svn repository via `git svn`? I don't want to do any fancy stuff, just get the the complet repo with externals.

Comment: there is https://github.com/andrep/git-svn-clone-externals

Answer (score 10, accepted):

git-svn doesn't support externals, but you may try [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) instead of git-svn. It supports svn:externals, converting them into .gitsvnextmodules file and displaying as modules. The only restriction: you should clone the repository with SmartGit instead of opening already existing git-svn repository.

Comment: The followup question: [Does SmartGit support git-svn?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16128118/86967)

Comment: Partially. It has compatibility and incompatibility modes. In the first one it fully emulates git-svn (hence doesn't support externals) in the second one it supports externals but not git-svn (i.e. git-svn commands will fail, you'll have to use UI to work with the repository). So you should choose.

Comment: SmartGit only creates a  .gitsvnextmodules and after calling "git submodule update --init --recursive" nothing happens. So I assume there is something not working correct...

Comment: It is written in the doc (http://wvvw.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/SVN+Integration) that "Only externals pointing to directories are supported, not externals pointing to individual files ('file externals')."

Answer (score 2):

I have been use git as a front end to access a SVN repository. The structure in SVN is generally pretty simple such that there is top level directory which has the externals in it and no externals in sub-directories. Also the externals don't really change much once they are added in. So assuming something like:

```
git svn clone X
cd X
```

I have had success getting all the externals with the following command:

```
git svn show-externals | \
 perl -ne 'if (/^\/(.*) (.*)/) { print "git svn clone $1 $2\n"; }' | \
 bash
```

I guess a more complicated structure for externals would require a more complicated perl script. Also, if your externals change you will need to do something similar again.

Comment: I found the above technique very useful - except I had to reverse $2 and $1 (the local dir and the remote)

Comment: @tutuDajuju glad to hear it helped. Thanks for commenting. I have noticed that too but I haven't spent the time to investigate why the ordering changes in some cases.

Comment: Perhaps the clone syntax changed between version? Today it's clone $url [$target_dir]  (dir is optional)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the external is a relative URL.  `^/OS/blah/blah` shows up as `/trunk/^/OS/blah/blah` with `git svn show-externals`.  Furthermore, `git svn clone` doesn't work on either `/trunk/^/OS/blah/blah` or `^/OS/blah/blah`.  However, I can of course clone the external using the full path.

Answer (score 2):

I post solution here that works in my case

```
git svn show-externals | \
  awk '/^\// { print "git svn clone "$3" ."$1" "$2":HEAD"  }' | \
  bash
```