# Does SmartGit support git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, smartgit

If SmartGit even supports git-svn, how would I go about using it? Would I clone my svn repository first then somehow link it to my git repository or vise versa? I found git-svn mentioned very briefly in the SmartGit documentation but it doesn't describe how to use it in the actual client.

Answer (score 1):

Following tutorial explains how the SVN integration of SmartGit works:

https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/SmartGit+as+SVN+Bridge

Comment: Link 'not found'

Comment: I did exactly this, but it only clones the trunk, without tags and branches