# Git svn not checking out everything it should

Tags: git, git-svn

I used git svn (version 1.7.10.msysgit.1) to check out a repository using the following steps:

In a fresh directory using git bash on windows 7

1) `git svn init "https://source/svn/repository/...pathToRepo..../trunk"` 
(I only care about the trunk - the repo is too massive to take entirely and I have no use for it all).

2) `git svn fetch -r HEAD` (because I don't care about any history either)

My problem is that while this appears to work and exits cleanly, a couple of files are missing in my version! If I use `tortoise-svn` to check out the repo, I get everything. I would have expected both of them to return the same results. The missing files are a few python files and some .png files. The set of missing files is always the same. I can't think of any reason that these files would be special. They are spread across a few directories, and I am using `kdiff3` (and manually verifying) that they are indeed different.

EDIT:
They were svn externals

Comment: Does `git svn show-ignore` return any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git-svn doesn't support externals out-of-the-box.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350651/how-do-i-keep-an-svnexternal-up-to-date-using-git-svn) describes a workaround that may work for you.

Comment: This seems to be the sort of thing I'd be looking for. I am using git svn at work and everyone else is using svn. So my requirements would be not only a script that will recursively find and clone all the externals, but that will also allow me to keep those externals up to date when I rebase (or by running some script every now and again). Any reccomendations based on experience?